# Could the word "artist" be used to refer to a writer?

Tags: vocabulary

According to the dictionary, artist could be a painter, singer, dancer, or actor.

But I think maybe writers could be considered artists as well.  What's your opinion?

I'm writing a composition about art and artists, and I'm not sure if a writer is appropriate as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if someone thought about it they would agree that writers are artists but the common thought of "artist" is a painter, singer, dancer, actor. A writer is not the first example that would spring to many minds.

Comment: At some point along the line some of them (singers and dancers especially) become 'artistes'. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: @Brian: A pompous French-inspired way of saying the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Language is meant to convey meaning or emotion, and linguistic art would be a happy use of the tools created to record events or write royal decrees. In calling a writer an artist, would you be misleading the reader? If so, is the deception or misdirection serving a purpose?

If you want to make the point that writers can be artists, it seems appropriate to acknowledge that some writers have gone beyond clarity and craft, creating a thing that someone, somewhere would define as art.

Answer (score 1):

There is some overlap between artists and writers, but not all writers are artists.

For example, Shakespeare is certainly an artist, but a person making a living writing as a writer of technical articles for MSDN probably is not (even if they authored a few books).

Of course, the line is subjective and can be disputed. Are bad poets artists? What about exceptionally good technical writers?